# Not using decimals but got Object of type Decimal is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, json, django, django-sessions

my view is working perfectly, but when i try to store a ModelForm result on session

it's stored but got Object of type Decimal is not JSON serializable

it doesn't make sens beceause i'm not storing Decimals on session

PS: i'm storing the ModelForm result on session because i have to redirect the user to an external url after he come back i need that data stored on session

**here is the view**

```
 def cart_detail(request):
    cart = Cart(request)
    order_form = OrderCreateForm()
    for item in cart:
        item['update_quantity_form'] = CartAddProductForm(initial={'quantity': item['quantity'], 'override': True})

    if cart.__len__() :
        if request.method == 'POST':
            order_form = OrderCreateForm(request.POST)
            if order_form.is_valid():
                order = order_form.save(commit=False)
                
                for item in order_form.cleaned_data.items():
                    request.session[str(item[0])] = str(item[1])
                    
                    print(request.session[str(item[0])])

              

                #also tried this way and same result
                # request.session['order_data'] = order_form.cleaned_data
                #also tried this way and same result

                # request.session['first_name'] = order_form.cleaned_data['first_name'] 
                # request.session['order_phone'] = str(order_form.cleaned_data['phone'])    
                # print('type => ', request.session['order_phone'])
              
                if request.user.is_authenticated:
                    order.user = request.user
                order.save()
                for item in cart:
                    OrderItem.objects.create(order=order,product=item['product'],price=item['price'],quantity=item['quantity'],attribute_1 = ['attrbute_1'], attribute_2 = ['attrbute_2'], attribute_3 = ['attrbute_3'])
                context = {
                    'order': order,
                    'total_price': total_price,
                    'delivery': order.delivery_cost,
                    'total_price_with_delivery': total_price_with_delivery,
                }
                
                print('here i am')

                return render(request, 'created.html', context)
            else: 
                print('errorforms', order_form.errors)
                messages.error(request, order_form.errors)
                return render(request, 'cart.html', {'cart':cart, 'form' : order_form, 'wilayas': wilayas, 'communes': communes})
        else:
            order_form = OrderCreateForm()
            if request.user.is_authenticated:
                initial_data = {
                    'first_name' : request.user.first_name,
                    'email' : request.user.email,
                    'phone' : request.user.profile.phone_number,
                    'address' : request.user.profile.address,
                }
                print('the form is not valid')
                order_form = OrderCreateForm(request.POST or None, initial=initial_data)
    context = {
        'cart': cart,
        'form' : order_form,
    }
    return render(request, 'cart.html', context)
```

** THE FORM **

```
class OrderCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = Order
    fields = ['first_name',  'address', 'campany', 'email', 'phone', 'wilaya', 'commune', 'note']
    required = ('phone',)
```

i don't think the problem is on session

i also commented out all methods on the Order Model

i don't even now where the problem actually is

**when i remove this block all works fine**

```
            for item in order_form.cleaned_data.items():
                request.session['order_data_'+str(item[0])] = str(item[1])
                print(request.session[str(item[0])])
```

but when it's here the print works

**EDIT**

here is cart.py

```
from decimal import Decimal
from django.conf import settings
from core.models import Product
from coupons.models import Coupon

class Cart(object):

def __init__(self, request):
    self.session = request.session
    
    #get the current cart 
    cart = self.session.get(settings.CART_SESSION_ID)
    if not cart:
        cart = self.session[settings.CART_SESSION_ID] = {}
    self.cart = cart
    #get current applied coupon
    self.coupon_id = self.session.get('coupon_id') 

    """
This method is defined as a property. If the cart contains 
a coupon_id attribute, the Coupon object with the given ID is returned.
"""


@property
def coupon(self):
    if self.coupon_id:
        try:
            return Coupon.objects.get(id=self.coupon_id, stock__gt=0)
        except Coupon.DoesNotExist:
            pass
    return None

def get_discount(self):
    if self.coupon:
        if self.coupon.discount_amount:
            return self.coupon.discount_amount
        else:
            discount = (self.coupon.discount_percentage / Decimal(100)) * self.get_total_price()
            return discount
    return Decimal(0)

# total price after discount = total price - discount price

def get_total_price_after_discount(self):
    price = self.get_total_price() - self.get_discount()
    if price < 0:
        price = 0
    return price

def save(self):
    self.session.modified = True



def add(self, product, quantity=1, override_quantity=False,attribute_1=False,attribute_2=False,attribute_3=False):
    product_id = str(product.id)
    if product_id not in self.cart:
        self.cart[product_id] = {'quantity': 0, 'price': str(product.price)}
       
    if override_quantity:
        self.cart[product_id]['quantity'] = quantity
    else:
        self.cart[product_id]['quantity'] = quantity

    self.save()



def remove(self, product):
    product_id = str(product.id)
    if product_id in self.cart:
        del self.cart[product_id]
        self.save()

def update(self, product, quantity):
    print('im on update cart view')
    product_id = str(product.id)
    self.cart[product_id]['quantity'] = quantity
    self.save()

def __iter__(self):
    product_ids = self.cart.keys()
    products = Product.published.filter(id__in=product_ids)
    cart = self.cart.copy()
    for product in products:
        cart[str(product.id)]['product'] = product
    for item in cart.values():
        item['price'] = Decimal(item['price'])
        item['total_price'] = item['price'] * item['quantity']
        yield item



def __len__(self):
    return sum(item['quantity'] for item in self.cart.values())

def get_total_price(self):
    return sum(Decimal(item['price']) * item['quantity'] for item in self.cart.values())



def clear(self):
    del self.session[settings.CART_SESSION_ID]
    self.save()
```

**Traceback**

```
  Internal Server Error: /fr/cart/

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\inter\Desktop\sunlab\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\inter\Desktop\sunlab\venv\lib\site-packages\sentry_sdk\integrations\django\middleware.py", line 175, in __call__
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\inter\Desktop\sunlab\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\deprecation.py", line 119, in __call__
    response = self.process_response(request, response)
  File "C:\Users\inter\Desktop\sunlab\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\sessions\middleware.py", line 61, in process_response
    request.session.save()
  File "C:\Users\inter\Desktop\sunlab\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\sessions\backends\db.py", line 83, in save
    obj = self.create_model_instance(data)
  File "C:\Users\inter\Desktop\sunlab\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\sessions\backends\db.py", line 70, in create_model_instance
    session_data=self.encode(data),
  File "C:\Users\inter\Desktop\sunlab\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\sessions\backends\base.py", line 114, in encode
    return signing.dumps(
  File "C:\Users\inter\Desktop\sunlab\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\signing.py", line 110, in dumps
    return TimestampSigner(key, salt=salt).sign_object(obj, serializer=serializer, compress=compress)
  File "C:\Users\inter\Desktop\sunlab\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\signing.py", line 172, in sign_object
    data = serializer().dumps(obj)
  File "C:\Users\inter\Desktop\sunlab\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\signing.py", line 87, in dumps
    return json.dumps(obj, separators=(',', ':')).encode('latin-1')
  File "c:\python38\lib\json\__init__.py", line 234, in dumps
    return cls(
  File "c:\python38\lib\json\encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "c:\python38\lib\json\encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "c:\python38\lib\json\encoder.py", line 179, in default
    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
TypeError: Object of type Product is not JSON serializable
[12/Feb/2022 10:40:07] "POST /fr/cart/ HTTP/1.1" 500 145079
```

Comment: First of all post the full traceback you get. It will tell you exactly where the error is. Then edit your code to represent [mre]. What is e.g. Cart?

Comment: i added the cart.py file where the cart object live,

Comment: and as i said i didn't add any Decimal to session so i don't klnow where the error could be

Comment: You still didn't add the traceback, but do you now see the Decimal objects - total price, price, discount...?

Comment: sorry i added it now but it didn"t tell any think that could help and i converted all decimals into int and now i have " TypeError at /fr/cart/ Object of type Product is not JSON serializable "
but i don't understand why is this hapenning only when i add order information to session ?

Comment: even if  i add request.session['hello'] = "hello" it triggers the same error

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is this line in cart.py

```
cart = self.session[settings.CART_SESSION_ID] = {}
```

You have set your cart to equal a value in your session dict and by doing so you are altering the session every time you change your cart. So by using Decimal or Product classes, Django is trying to serialize before you sanitize your data. You should  perform your logic before setting the session variable.

I think you would be better off using a model for what you’re trying to do though. You also will want to calculate your prices in cents (or smallest unit for whatever currency) to avoid rounding errors.

Edited for further clarification:

In cart.py you have the following line.

```
cart = self.session[settings.CART_SESSION_ID] = {}
```

From right to left, you are assigning `{}` to `self.session[settings.CART_SESSION_ID]` and then `self.session[settings.CART_SESSION_ID]` to `cart`

So for example, looking at this block of code

```
def __iter__(self):
    ...
    for item in cart.values():
        item['price'] = Decimal(item['price'])
    ...
```

You are not just changing cart.item.price. You are also changing `self.session[setting.CART_SESSION_ID].item.price`. The issue is that in Django, whenever you alter session, it serializes your changes to JSON. Since self.session references the user session (in `__init__`), Django is trying to serialize a Decimal object and gives you an error.

To fix this, you can change the relevant part of your `__init__` from

```
cart = self.session.get(settings.CART_SESSION_ID) 
if not cart:
    cart = self.session[settings.CART_SESSION_ID] = {}
self.cart = cart
```

to

```
cart = self.session.get(settings.CART_SESSION_ID)
self.cart = cart.copy() if cart else {}
```

and make your `save()` method

```
def save():
    self.session.modified=True
    self.session[settings.CART_SESSION_ID] = self.cart
```